# How to browse or search comments?

Tags: support, comment, search

SE is already very good in keeping each individual user's record on their questions raised and their answers posted. I am wondering is it also possible to keep track of their comments made too?  Then it would be easier for one to review them at a click of a button (or a link).

Comment: That would be [useful](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/42351/mick?tab=activity&sort=comments) :-)

Answer (score 16):

Under your profile, there is a tab called "activity."  Under this you will find several filters.  One of them is "comments."

[image: demonstration]

Comment: +1 Good catch :-)

Comment: However only recent comments can be seen. What about older comments? A comment may be as useful as answer.

Comment: @user10676 What do you mean by recent? As far as I can tell, it has all activity there.

Comment: Indeed, all 3,204 of my comments since [my very first one on MSE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3192/gauge-transformations-in-differential-forms/3202#comment7216_3202) seem to be there ... all 161 pages of them.

Comment: Great. The "activity" has what I wanted.

Answer (score 9):

If browsing through the comments list in your profile takes too long, you can search them through  Data Explorer:

- [Search your comments](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/76958/search-your-comments) (or another user's  comments, by entering their User Id)
- [Comments left by a user on your posts](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/113150/comments-left-by-a-user-on-your-posts) (more generally, comments left by user A on posts by user B)
- [Search **all** comments](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/114513/search-comments)

and my favorite

- [Posts edited after your comment](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/113603/posts-edited-after-your-comment)

E.g., suppose you request clarification of a question, the OP eventually edits the post but does not @-mention you in a comment. The query finds all such instances. Same for typos you point out: once they are corrected, the comment can be removed. Also, downvotes.

Comment: The search program is powerful. If I may, I would like to suggest an enhancement (= provide options or an example for the field 'pattern'). It is difficult for a newbie like me to guess what should be filled.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the original question, but Data Explorer also has [list a user's positive score comments, sorted by score](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/47432/my-comment-scores) If you want the zero score comments too, it wouldn't be hard to change the code.